# Python matplotlib Colorfunction

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I would like to use a `ColorFunction` similar to that in [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) for my plots in python.

In other words, I would like to call `pyplot.plot(x, y, color=c)`, where `c` is a vector, defining the color of each data point.

Is there any way to achieve this using the matplotlib library?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no equivalent in Matplotlib, but we can get the similar result following two steps: draw points with varied colors and draw the line.

Here is a demo.

[image]

---

The source code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import random

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nrof_points = 100 
x = np.linspace(0, 10, nrof_points)
y = np.sin(x)
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, nrof_points))     # generate a bunch of colors

# draw points
for idx, point in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o', color=colors[idx], markersize=10)

# draw the line
ax.plot(x, y, 'k')
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @SparkAndShine that there is no way to parameterize the color of *one* line, it is possible to color many lines to create a visual effect that is largely the same.  This is at the heart of a demo in the [MatPlotLib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).  However, this demo is not the simplest implementation of this principle.  Here is an alternate demo based on @SparkAndShine's response:

[colored sine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRm4b.png) (can't post as image since I don't have the reputation)

---

Source code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nrof_points = 100 
x = np.linspace(0, 10, nrof_points)
y = np.sin(x)
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, nrof_points))     # generate a bunch of colors

# draw points
for idx in range(0,np.shape(x)[0]-2,1):
    ax.plot(x[idx:idx+1+1], y[idx:idx+1+1], color=colors[idx])

# add a grid and show
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```